# Can't translate block in Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, block

I am building site in Drupal and I need your help. I have an assignment to make one more language translation of the site, and so far so good. However, I have one trouble with one block which isn't going to get translated, even though in the settings I translated it.

Also one strange activity I noticed is that when I try to go to VIEW section of all the other languages, I get dropped to front page (where that block is actually located) but if I press `VIEW` from my language translation (Swedish) of the block I get to completely new page.

If I go to front page and my language is selected, that block is actually using default language.

Any help what may cause it?

Answer (score 1):

For desire url aliasing you need to install pathauto drupal module. then you can configure alise from below url

admin/config/search/path/patterns

Answer (score 0):

OK, I have found a solution to this problem.
It appears that Drupal 7 by default sets your new language homepage to the default homepage and that's why this block was using default language since it was relying on the front page. Anyway, to fix the issue follow the steps:

Login to adming account, go to Configuration, System, Site Information and in the field Default front page for the language you have chosen navigate to your specific node page. That's it.